# Plot Graph in Console by printing special character say * and spaces using matrix structure in Perl

Tags: perl, graph

My task is to plot Least Mean Squared Error (LSME) values from each iteration of a machine learning algorithm in a Graph of X and Y axes/coordinates. I decided to print special character (say *) on the console using loops. I do not want to use any libraries for graph plotting but to be simple by printing sequence of special character so that I may be able to print first quadrant of X-Y coordinates onto console.

I recall my initial programming assignments in Java to print different shapes on console like Pyramid, Square, Rectangle, Circle etc. using for and while loops. Also, I am familiar with NDC to view port mapping in graphics programming. But I am unable to implement such nested loops that print my required graph in first quadrant on console as same that we draw on paper.

On console, the origin (0,0) is top left corner of console. But on paper the origin is left bottom if we only plot first quadrant. For overcoming this problem I cracked an idea that I use a 2 D matrix structure and some transpose operation of it and use characters (BLANK SPACE and *) for plotting my graph. I developed following code which has two arrays, one with error values (LMSE) and the other one with the count of spaces.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$|= 1;

my @values = (0.7,0.9,2,0.1,1.2,2.4,0.4,3.5,4.9); # Float error values with 1 decimal place
my @values2;

my $XAxis_LMSE = scalar @values;
my ($minLMSE_Graph, $maxLMSE_Graph) = (sort {$a <=> $b} @values)[0, -1];

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @values; $i++) {
    my $rem = $maxLMSE_Graph - $values[$i];
    push (@values2, $rem);
}
```

I computed maximum value of my error values array and assigned the difference of Max value with original error value to another array. The logic which I am able to conceive is that I fill a matrix with spaces and * which when printed on console depict a X-Y first quadrant graph on console. Is my approach promising? Can somebody confirm my approach is correct and how to build such a matrix of " " and "*" characters?

Y(x) values are given by array @values and X is number of Iterations. Iterations can go from 1 to say 100. While Y(x) also remains an Integer. Its a simple Column Bar Graph. Below is a sample graph in Excel but the column Bars will be series of character "*" on console. It will be a vertical Bar Graph.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should look like for the given sample array? This could help clarify your question

Comment: What is `@values` -- is that `y(x)`? (So that `7` is `y` at `x=1` and `9` is `y` at `x=2`, etc?)

Comment: Yes you are right. Y(x) is values given by @values. and X is number of Iterations. Iterations can go from 1 to say 100. While Y(x) also remains an Integer.

Comment: Its a simple Column Bar Graph with Y(x) values given in @values and X be the number of iterations.

Comment: I edited my question in response of the two comments.

Comment: Made edits to my asnwer with `gnuplot` -- improved the plot and added another way to do it (without a Perl module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While libraries are dismissed by the question, the requirements elaborated in comments (large x-axis span, floating point values, particular data ranges) make it hard to do justice to the problem by a hand-rolled snippet like in my other answer.

So here is an example using the great [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) library, which has many features and publication quality plots.  Learning it isn't hard, with lots of resources and examples.

The library does have an option to print to what it calls "dumb" terminal, ie. ascii, the main need here.  And then there is an endless stream of options for exactly how to plot, some very sophisticated.  But basic plotting is dirt simple.

There is also a wrapper module for Perl, [Chart::Gnuplot](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart::Gnuplot), which makes it simpler yet.<sup>†</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Path::Tiny;  # path()->slurp
use List::Util qw(max min);
use Chart::Gnuplot;

#my $outfile = shift // 'ascii_gnuplot.out';

my @y = (0.7, 0.9, 2, 0.1, 1.2, 2.4, 0.4, 3.5, 4.9);
my @x = 1 .. @y;
# Or, to see how it goes about large span of x-axis
#demo_large_x_span(\@x, \@y);

my $y_min = min @y;
my $yrange_min = $y_min > 0 ? 0 : $y_min;

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new( 
    terminal  => 'dumb',  # ascii
    xrange    => [min(@x), max @x], 
    yrange    => [$yrange_min, max @y], 
    title     => "Least Mean Squared Error with iterations",
    timestamp => { 
        fmt    => '%d/%m/%y %H:%M',
        offset => "6, -1",
    },
    #output    => $outfile,
);
# All options can be given in the constructor itself
# but these are particular for plotting in terminal
$chart->set( 
    xtics => { length => 0 },  # don't show tics
    ytics => { length => 0 },
    x2tics => undef,
    y2tics => undef,
    key => undef,              # no legend with filename
);

my $dataset = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => \@x,
    ydata => \@y,
    style => "impulses",  # "dots" for scatter plot
);

$chart->plot2d($dataset);  # done. shows on screen or in "output" file

sub demo_large_x_span {
    my ($xref, $yref, $max_x) = @_;
    $max_x //= 200;
    for (1 .. $max_x) {
        if ($_ % 10 == 0) {
           push @$xref, $_;
           push @$yref, sqrt($_); #$_*0.5;
        }
    }
}
```

If this fails to print the ascii graph to terminal then uncomment the `output => $outfile` option (and the filename's definition). Then open and print the file out of the program.<sup>‡</sup>

The above program prints

```
                    Least Mean Squared Error with iterations

      +-------+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+------+-------*
  4.5 +                                                                    *
      |                                                                    *
    4 +                                                                    *
      |                                                                    *
  3.5 +                                                            *       *
    3 +                                                            *       *
      |                                                            *       *
  2.5 +                                             *              *       *
    2 +                      *                      *              *       *
      |                      *                      *              *       *
  1.5 +                      *                      *              *       *
      |                      *              *       *              *       *
    1 +              *       *              *       *              *       *
  0.5 +       *      *       *              *       *              *       *
      |       *      *       *              *       *       *      *       *
    0 +-------*------*-------*-------*------*-------*-------*------*-------*
      0       1      2       3       4      5       6       7      8       9

      12/09/22 01:09
```

I suggest to review the many, many options available so to get a feel for what kinds of plots are possible and how well one can craft a plot.

A nice overview is in [gnuplot demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/) and then in [Chart::Gnuplot gallery and examples](http://chartgnuplot.sourceforge.net/).

Finally, a grand advantage of using a library for this is that by "flipping a switch" one can have a top-notch plot in one of many formats (change `terminal` setting, or simply drop it and name the output file with the extension of the desired graphics format).

---

<sup>†</sup> Use of this module isn't necessary.  One can write a file with specifications for `gnuplot` and then run `gnuplot` on that file, out of the program.  (I'd consider this to be an overall simpler way, if one is comfortable with `gnuplot`'s commands.)

Here is how to obtain the above plot that way

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(max min);

my @y = (0.7, 0.9, 2, 0.1, 1.2, 2.4, 0.4, 3.5, 4.9);
my @x = 1 .. @y;

my ($datafile, $gp_file) = build_plot_cmd(\@x, \@y);

system( "gnuplot $gp_file" ) == 0 or die $!;

sub build_plot_cmd {
    my ($xref, $yref) = @_; 

    # Write data to a file for gnuplot (can also use "inline" data)
    my $data_gp = 'data.gp';
    open my $fh_d, '>', $data_gp or die $!;
    for my $i (0 .. $#$xref) {
        say $fh_d "$xref->[$i] $yref->[$i]";
    }
    close $fh_d;

    my $x_max = max @$xref;
    my $y_min = min @$yref;
    my $yrange_min = $y_min > 0 ? 0 : $y_min;
    my $y_max = max @$yref;

    # Build gnuplot command-file and then write it
    my $gp_cmd = <<"END_CMD_FILE";
# Plot LMSE vs number of iterations
set term dumb   # feed 80 40
set xrange [0:$x_max]
set yrange [$yrange_min:$y_max]
set title "Least Mean Squared Error with iterations"

set xtics scale 0 nomirror
set ytics scale 0
unset y2tics
unset key

plot '$data_gp' with impulses

END_CMD_FILE

    my $gp_file = 'set_cmd.gp';
    open my $fh_gp, '>', $gp_file  or die $!;
    say $fh_gp $gp_cmd;
    close $fh_gp;

    return $data_gp, $gp_file;
}
```

This prints out the same plot to terminal, with tiny differences.  Do as you please with generated files; the program can remove them, or use `File::Temp` in the first place -- or name them carefully and keep for posteriority (in a separate directory perhaps).

---

<sup>‡</sup> Files meant to be temporary can be made and managed using [File::Temp](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Temp)

Comment: Thanks. Both options are possible for me. I prefer installing gnuplot on windows. However your both solution attempts made my task complete.

Comment: @P_Z Great :)  I can absolutely recommend gnuplot -- if you need an occasional plot, either quick-and-dirty or nice, there's plenty of examples around; if you'll need a plotting tool for systemic work, it has tons and tons of features, with consistent interface (if you don't mind writing files for plots instead of clicking on buttons in a GUI, like in Origin (commercial) or such)

Answer (score 4):

*Update in requirements is a game-changer.  See discussion and code furhter below.*

---

One way, with originally posted integer data (see below for updated requirements)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(max min);

# =================================
# Data posted originally (integer): 
#   in code; with a negative value added; in Excel graph
# ======================================================
my @vals = (7,9,2,0,1,2,4,3,9);
#my @vals = (7,9,2,0,1,2,4,3,-2,9);
#my @vals = (38, 32, 28, 29, 34, 31, 15, 43, 43, 11, 4, 34);

my $max_y = max @vals;
my $min_y = min @vals;

my $min_y_to_show = ($min_y >= 0) ? 1 : $min_y;

for my $y (reverse $min_y_to_show .. $max_y) {
    printf "%2d | ", $y;  # y-axis: value for this row (and "axis")
    say join '',
        map { $_ >= $y ? ' * ' : ' 'x3 } @vals;
}
# x-axis, with its values
say ' 'x4, '-'x(3*@vals);
say ' 'x4, join '', map { sprintf "%3d", $_ } 1..@vals;
```

Prints

```
 9 |     *                    * 
 8 |     *                    * 
 7 |  *  *                    * 
 6 |  *  *                    * 
 5 |  *  *                    * 
 4 |  *  *              *     * 
 3 |  *  *              *  *  * 
 2 |  *  *  *        *  *  *  * 
 1 |  *  *  *     *  *  *  *  * 
    ---------------------------
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

I've made a few presentational choices of substance: to always plot down to `1` (even if all data are greater) and to not show zero -- unless there are negative values, when all is shown (add a negative value to `@vals` to test).  These are changed fairly easily.

There's also some trivial formatting choices, for layout/spacing etc.

Otherwise there isn't anything manual really.  Change `@vals` to plot a different data set,<sup>†</sup> hopefully in the same style. This wasn't tested much.

---

*Update in the question introduces floating point (decimal) values. This is further elaborated in comments, what altogether amounts to a library-grade project.  And some of these wants are just not possible in ASCII in a terminal, where "plotting" goes by character and we only have a 100 or so.  Here is code updated for what is feasible here, and some discussion.*

To accommodate floating point values (with one digit of precision we are told), the y-axis now need be plotted in smaller increments ("divisions" -- "ticks"), lest we fail to show a lot of data if they are lumped within an integer.

Then, how to divide it?  Below I show all data within 20 rows, and with a row for the smallest value added if needed.  From that a division is worked out, for the given data set (updated in the question).  If the data are clustered around some value far from zero then this isn't good of course (imagine data between 2.8 and 3.9, going by 0.1; why would we plot bars all the way from zero?).  But one has to make decisions for a given data set, what can be done automatically as well.

This necessarily leads to some imprecision in how data is shown.  Showing *every* data point correctly isn't feasible in general in a terminal.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(max min);
    
my @vals = (0.7, 0.9, 2, 0.1, 1.2, 2.4, 0.4, 3.5, 4.9);

my $n_rows = 20;

my $max_y = max @vals;
my $min_y = min @vals;

# Show from at least the smallest y-division ("tick");
# at first use 0 and then work out the "tick" and adjust
my $min_y_to_show = $min_y >= 0 ? 0 : $min_y;
my $y_tick = ($max_y - $min_y_to_show) / $n_rows;
# Now once we have the y-division ("tick") adjust 
$min_y_to_show = $min_y >= $y_tick ? $y_tick : $min_y;

say "Smallest division for y = $y_tick\n";

my @y_axis = map { $y_tick * $_ } 1 .. $n_rows;
unshift @y_axis, $min_y_to_show if $min_y_to_show < $y_axis[0];

for my $y (reverse @y_axis) {
    printf "%4.2f | ", $y;
    say join '', 
        map { $_ >= $y ? ' * ' : ' 'x3 } @vals;
}
say ' 'x6, '-'x(3*@vals);
say ' 'x6, join '', map { sprintf "%3d", $_ } 1..@vals;
```

Prints

```
Smallest division for y = 0.245

4.90 |                          * 
4.66 |                          * 
4.41 |                          * 
4.17 |                          * 
3.92 |                          * 
3.68 |                          * 
3.43 |                       *  * 
3.19 |                       *  * 
2.94 |                       *  * 
2.70 |                       *  * 
2.45 |                       *  * 
2.21 |                 *     *  * 
1.96 |        *        *     *  * 
1.72 |        *        *     *  * 
1.47 |        *        *     *  * 
1.23 |        *        *     *  * 
0.98 |        *     *  *     *  * 
0.74 |     *  *     *  *     *  * 
0.49 |  *  *  *     *  *     *  * 
0.25 |  *  *  *     *  *  *  *  * 
0.10 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
      ---------------------------
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

In further discussion in comments it is explained that `x`-values may actually go into hundreds. That would have to be scaled (can't show 500 data points in a 100-char wide terminal) but then that comes with further decisions to make since not all data can be shown.

This amounts to much too much for a Stackoverflow Q-A. There are just too many details to be specified and decided on. Hopefully the discussion and code above is helpful for people to work out more elaborate scenarios.

Finally, if all this adds up to too much I can recommend `gnuplot` used out of Perl.  It produces publication quality plots and it's fairly simple to use for simple things -- once learned, what isn't a terrible task with all the resources and example out there.

Otherwise, there are a number of other Perl libraries for graphing of various kinds.

---

<sup>†</sup>  This is for data shown in the original version of the question (seen in the code here)

With the values picked from the image of an Excel graph shown in the question, instead of the `@vals` used above (from the question's code), it prints

```
43 |                       *  *          
42 |                       *  *          
41 |                       *  *          
40 |                       *  *          
39 |                       *  *          
38 |  *                    *  *   
37 |  *                    *  *          
36 |  *                    *  *          
35 |  *                    *  *          
34 |  *           *        *  *        * 
33 |  *           *        *  *        * 
32 |  *  *        *        *  *        * 
31 |  *  *        *  *     *  *        * 
30 |  *  *        *  *     *  *        * 
29 |  *  *     *  *  *     *  *        * 
28 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
27 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
26 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
25 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
24 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
23 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
22 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
21 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
20 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
19 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
18 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
17 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
16 |  *  *  *  *  *  *     *  *        * 
15 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        * 
14 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        * 
13 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        * 
12 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *        * 
11 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
10 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
 9 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
 8 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
 7 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
 6 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
 5 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *     * 
 4 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
 3 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
 2 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
 1 |  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * 
    ------------------------------------
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: There is also `minmax` in [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils), for `my ($min, $max) = minmax @data;`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only problem I am facing is that the number of Iterations along x-axis are big values. The algorithm revealed 74 iterations so when I replaced the @vals with mine, the graph is distorted and displaying x-axis number on two lines. Can we modify your logic so that the graph is scaled (as per aspect ratio). But if number of iterations are fairly large then simple vertical histogram plotting would not be feasible, like iterations = 500, 1000 etc. Can we rotate current graph clock-wise by 90 degrees so that y-axis is horizontal line.......

Comment: with calibration (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 till say 5.0) from left to right. And X-axis is vertical line from top to bottom with calibration (in integers from 1, 2, 3,, and so on till maximum iterations). Sorry about not elaborating my requirements clearly. Also my error values Y(X) can be float values with 1 decimal place. Like minimum would be 0.0, and then 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 till say 5.0. The maximum Y(X) would be not large enough (less than 10) but iterations can be 1000 etc.

Comment: @P_Z Heh, that changes things -- it's a library-grade requirement now :)  Please keep in mind that ASCII "art" is going to have limitations: it's plotting by character, and that's up to about a 100 or so for a terminal (a bit less vertically). Once you start scaling these axes then we're dealing with general plotting/graphing, with all kinds of issues.  All this can be done but it makes it a far more rounded project.  I'll see what can be done reasonably within a stackoverflow Q-A.  (I looked for a library of this kind but not very thoroughly...)

Comment: @P_Z Updated to what I think is feasible to do here (and it already added up to too much perhaps, with a long post while some decisions are perhaps being questionable).  Let me know if there are questions

Comment: Ok, so what should I do now? I think Histogram type chart or graph is better for clear visibility.

Comment: @P_Z If a histogram is good for you then that's different -- you can always bin data so that it fits nicely in a terminal -- say, 20-50 bins, each shown with 3 spaces. (But you never mentioned binning data so I don't know whether that's good for your needs.) On the other hand, the trouble stems from the fact that you want to plot ASCII in the terminal -- why? With a proper plotting program, which can be driven out of a script, there'd be no trouble. If you don't know those then there'd be a little overhead to learn one but then that will be useful for the future.

Comment: Using a library is the only reasonable way I see to get to all your needs, including printing ascii to terminal (gnuplot can do that).  I posted another answer with an example (will edit, too)